# Image array for javascript slideshow not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, slideshow

I'm making a slideshow in javascript for a class assignment and I have the slideshow working but it's not displaying the images. I can see that the image icon changes but the actual image is not showing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //put images in array
        var pics = new Array();
        pics[0] = new Image();
        pics[0].src = "images/forest.jpg";
        pics[1] = new Image();
        pics[1].src = "images/mountains.jpg";
        pics[2] = new Image();
        pics[2].src = "images/nature.jpg";
        pics[3] = new Image();
        pics[3].src = "images/snowtops.jpg";
        var index = 0; //start point
        var piclength = pics.length - 1;

        function slideshow() {
            document.slide.src = pics[index];
            if (index < piclength) {
                index++;
            }
            else {
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        function slide() {
            setInterval(slideshow, 3000);
        }
    </script>

<body onload="slide()">
    <h1>Nature Photography</h1>
    <main>
        <section>
            <p>I am an enthusiastic about nature photography. Here is a slideshow of my 
works.</p>
            <aside> <img id="myImage" src="images/forest.jpg" name="slide" width="95%"> 
</aside>
```

Comment: You need to read a basic example of DOM manipulation. HTML just doesn't work like that.  you need to use appendchild or something

Answer (score 0):

First, I would put the script tag after your HTML. This will allow you to cache DOM elements without waiting for the "DOMContentLoaded" event or the "load" (window) event to be fired.
Second, you should cache the "myImage" element. Something like `const slider = document.getElementById('myImage')`.
Third, check your console. Maybe your image URLs are wrong? And make sure your HTML is valid. From what you posted, you are missing a lot of things (doctype, html/head tags, you didn't close body tag and similar)

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I actually figured out why the images weren't showing. document.slide.src = pics[index]; was actually supposed to be document.slide.src = pics[index].src;